# Opencart Gzip Output Compression Level not working

Tags: gzip, opencart

When I enable Opencart's Output Compression Level from admin menu, browsers are not loading my page

For Example, google chrome gives the below result:

330 (net:: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.

Opera shows unknown special charaters etc.

How can I find the reason behind this error ?

Comment: The reason could be You have some PHP error (even a poor Notice is enough) so before the gzipped output the PHP not gzipped error message is outputted. This is one of the reasons browsers cannot display the output, coz they was given some output compression header and when trying to decompress the uncompressed error message it fails...

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your corresponding tpl would solve the problem.

```
<?php
ini_set("zlib.output_compression", "Off");
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It will just avoid compression at all, see system/library/response.php, function compress.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the shop / admin you instead of the content displayed this error - disable compression in the store settings.
Given that access to the admin in this case, you probably will not be, you can perform the following query over phpmyadmin (after opening your database):

```
UPDATE `{PREFIKS_TABLITS setting`} SET ` value` = '0' WHERE `group` = 'config' AND ` key` = 'config_compression' ;
```

PREFIKS_TABLITS {} you can see in the file the config.php :

```
define ( 'DB_PREFIX' , 'oc_' );
```

Original : https://opencartforum.com/topic/15067-resheno-error-330-neterr_content_decoding_failed/